# How to get http content using an given API key like this in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

http://ssw.com/profile/?apikey = skdwkdkfkkdj

I tried to use

```
public async Task<string> GetFromUriAsync(string requestUri, string token)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUri);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("apikey", "=" + token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }
```

Then it returns null

Am I missing something or is it just totally wrong?

Comment: You have a URL. Why are you trying to split it up and not just using it as it is?

Comment: is `apikey` a query string or a header?

Comment: also try removing `"="` in `"=" + token`

Comment: oh , i now have some clue, thanks i'll try again

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass the API key in the header information of your HTTP request. What you need to do is just pass that whole URL without any additional header information.

IE: use "http://ssw.com/profile?apikey=abcdef" as the requestUri and send token as null. Also, remove the setting of the client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization property. Authorization was meant to be a user/pass system and not a token-based system.

To test this, download Fiddler 4 (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler). Once you have fiddler installed, on the "Composer" tab, you can test different queries you need by putting the URL directly into the URL box and clicking "Execute". You'll then be able to use the inspectors to see the responses and figure out where you need to go from there.

Here are the classes I use for HTTP GET and POST operations:

```
    public static string HTTPGET(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 100000;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            if (responseStream != null)
                using (StreamReader resStream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    return resStream.ReadToEnd();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string HTTPPOST(string url, string postData)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (Stream responseStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                if (responseStream != null)
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        return responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url);
            Console.WriteLine(postData);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```